# In TOS, how many shuttlecraft were aboard the U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the original series, how many shuttlecraft made up the normal complement aboard the U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701? The numbering convention I found on [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_shuttlecraft) goes up to NCC-1701/12, listing both active and destroyed, with the Galileo accounting for 3 of the 10 shown. How many were supposed to be onboard?

Comment: I'm pretty sure our old friend *The Making of Star Trek* answers this, and I believe the answer is 2, but without a copy of the book I'm not going to make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As referenced on the Memory Alpha Wiki, the standard complement on the original Enterprise (and likely ships of her size and class) was four [Class-F shuttlecraft](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Class_F_shuttlecraft).

Comment: Been a while since I looked at them, but the original blueprints that were released said something like room for two or three on the flight deck and then the turntable was also an elevator to a lower level maintanance bay where two more could stationed at any given time.  I need to go pull those out again.

Comment: From some of the Starfleet Battles games allowed for six. Three on the flight deck, two below decks and one on the elevator launch pad. But at 24 feet long, four to six seems reasonable.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze Dang. I looked around M.A. before I posted the question. Thanks. BTW, any insight to the naming/numbering convention?

Comment: Odds are they would number them sequentially, partially to track the number of craft to have ever served onboard the Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

In the TOS episode "Omega Glory", it is stated the Exeter starship (like the E) has four shuttlecrafts aboard.  I would presume the E 1701 would also carry four.

Answer (score 0):

except during "The Enemy Within" when nobody mentions using shuttlecraft to erscue Sulu's group from the planet without using the dangerous transporter.  Thus everyone must have known that, for various reasons,  there were no shuttles available.  In that episode the Enterprise was carrying a lot fewer shuttles than normally.

Comment: That is because the production team had not yet built a shuttlecraft set.

Comment: In-universe the weather was probably too dangerous for a shuttlecraft.